# Double submit, prevent default not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope someone can help me.

I have two buttons on my page in my form. "Save" and "Publish". This is the HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="publish" value="true" onclick="publishAlbum({{ album.id }}, '{{ album.title }}')">Publish</button>
```

The first one saves the album, the second one sends an e-mail to the owner. The second one ("Publish") needs to trigger a confirm first ("Are you sure?"). When you click "Ok", the form should submit, but if you click "Cancel" (in the confirm box), it should do nothing.

Here is my JS:

```
function publishAlbum(album_id, album_title)
    {
        var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to publish this album?');

        if(!result)
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

I tried literally everything (prevent default, return etc), but every time I click "Cancel", the form still submits and the e-mail is sent.

Can someone help me?

Comment: A "Cancel" button is not a default form control. You've to cancel the default action in the submit handler, not in an arbitrary click handler.

Comment: "I tried literally everything (prevent default" You don't even pass event object to your click handler how did you try to prevent default action then?

Comment: Show your code or it didn't happen. ;)

Comment: @Teemu I mean the "Cancel" button in the confirm box..

Comment: @Yury, I tried to prevent the event with passing an e together with the {{album.id }} etc but did not work.

Comment: If you are using this type of “old school” event handling (_why_ for crying out loud, if you are using jQuery already?) via HTML attributes, you need to return true/false “from” there - `onclick="return foo();"`

Comment: @R-b-n The handler of Publish button is the arbitrary event handler I meant. Anyway, something doesn't match here. Button of type of button doesn't submit a form by default. How would the form be submitted when clicking Publish button? Have you omitted some code from `publishAlbum` function?

Answer (score 0):

Publish

```
$('.publish-button').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let albumId = $('#selectYourAlbumId');
  let albumTitle = $('#selectYourAlbumTitle');
  var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to publish this album?');
    if(!result)
    {
        return;
    }
  // POST your form through an AJAX call

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the event object somehow (e.g. by adding an event listener to the button). Then you are able to prevent the form submission, like so:

```js
const album = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Test',
};

document.querySelector('[name=publish]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!publishAlbum(album.id, album.title)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

function publishAlbum(album_id, album_title) {
  var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to publish this album?');

  if (!result) {
    return false;
  }

  // do your stuff
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://example.org" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="publish" value="Publish" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have these buttons inside a form tag, you can try this:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Confirm Box</h2>


<button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="publish" value="true" onclick="publishAlbum()" id="myButton">Publish</button>

<script>
function publishAlbum() {
    var txt;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        $("#myButton").trigger('submit');
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
        alert(txt)
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form-publish .button-publish').on("click", function(e) {
        var c = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (c) {
            return;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```